# What's the English verb/phrase for going back on action when playing chess?

Tags: phrases, verbs

The other day I was playing chess with my friend who constantly went back on his move and ask to restart again whenever he made a wrong move/decision. What's the idiomatic verb/phrase to describe his action of going back on his move?

Comment: Isn't a redo called a Mulligan?

Comment: Tongue-in-cheek reference to loading a savegame in video games: "**Save scumming** is where something happens in a game that you don't like as a result of your actions, and so you load an earlier save for a chance to undo it. It's cheating, in other words – and depending on who you ask, mainly cheating yourself."

Comment: @YosefBaskin I think the applicability of mulligan would depend on whether the opponent _immediately_ asks to try another move (yes), or whether he only suggests it after the OP has made a clearly superior move (no).

Comment: I've heard ***rescind***, ***retract***, and ***revoke*** used in this context.

Comment: I once spent many hours over many days playing chess with a guy who was *way* above me in ability. We only actually *started* the game once, after which whenever I thought I was in a hopeless position he would offer to ***backtrack*** as many moves as I wanted, until I felt I was no longer at a disadvantage. He never actually wrote anything down, but I'm sure he was accurately backtracking even when I needed to retrace a dozen moves or more. It certainly taught me a lot though (but I must admit the main thing I learned was that I simply wasn't in his league, and never would be! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers  thanks for your word and your story. 'backtract' sound bit formal than 'take back'?

Comment: @user239460: I wouldn't say ***backtrack*** is in any way "formal". But I think you might be more likely to call it backtracking if *several* moves are being retracted, as opposed to *Do you want to **take back** your [**single** most recent] move?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers get it, thanks. i know it more clearly now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've seen **takeback** used to describe this action of taking back a move in Chess.

Definition on [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/takeback):

> #### Noun
>
> **takeback** (*plural* takebacks)
>
> 1. The act of taking back or reclaiming anything
> 2. (chess) The withdrawal of the previous move, as in practice games.

I've also seen **Takeback Game** used to describe a game of Chess where takebacks are allowed acording to the rules.

For more examples, you can check out [the usage of this word on the Chess Stack Exchange site](https://chess.stackexchange.com/search?q=takeback).

---

Another word that might work here to describe your friend's action can be **undid** or **undo**.

Comment: This is also the word used on chess playing sites for the command that asks the opponent to let you take back your last move.

Comment: It's not strictly allowed when following official rules of chess, but [this question on chess SE](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/2671/is-takeback-allowed-in-real-chess) indeed uses the term *takeback* in the question and all of the answers.

Comment: And if you want to deny your friend the right to rescind moves, you have to say "no ["takesies backsies"](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=taksies%20backsies).

Comment: This is the right answer

Comment: thanks. that's a good word, only that my question was asking for a verb/phrase, but you give me a noun.

Comment: @user239460 "Takeback" is the term to describe this kind of action. You can use the term as part of a sentence like, "My friend preformed a *takeback* move". In verb form, you can split the term into two words and simply say, "My friend *took back* his move."

Comment: alright, i shall take it.

Answer (score 4):

**Renege** is often used if a single move is taken back.

From [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/renege)

> transitive verb
>
> :  deny, renounce
>
> intransitive verb
>
> 1 obsolete :  to make a denial
>
> 2 :  revoke
>
> 3 :  to go back on a promise or commitment

Other sources, including [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/renege) include:

> In a card game, to break one's commitment to follow suit when capable.

I've seen it used in other games, including chess, when a person makes (or attempts to make) a move discovered to be illegal.

Answer (score 3):

Once his hand leaves the piece he isn't allowed to "**take-back**" the move. I've also played by the rule that once you touch a piece, you must move that piece, and once you let it go, that player's turn has ended.